# Typo3 | CookieConsent2 change message

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, cookieconsent

I got the problem that I cannot change the message shown in the box. Even though I changed the message in the file:

```
'Root/typo3conf/ext/cookieconsent2/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xlf'
```

I first thought there could be another file but I were not able to find any other and my next guess was maybe a problem with the cache. But this did not work either.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Messages of the translationfiles are cached, so if you changed something in these files you've to delete the cache in the backend (administration-interface) of TYPO3.

Furthermore perhaps you edited the wrong file. The file you posted is for German language and to display that you've to have or create a setup for the German language. The English files never have the prefix "de." or any other prefix.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I know this is the german file, because it is a german website, but I also changed the english file, because the website is multilanguage. Could you say me where I can delete the Cache? I really struggling to find this.


Edit: I thought I found it, but this were just the temp files of the user.

Comment: Let me know if the messages are shown correct now or if you still need help with this issue.

Comment: I solved the problem. I added a little extension which adds a button to just delete the files in the l10n folder. Thank you for you support.