# TYPO3 6.2 CookieConsent2 change message text

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I've got the same problem as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674651/typo3-cookieconsent2-change-message) (I read the thread):

I got the problem that I cannot change the message shown in the box. Even though I changed the message in the file:
`Root/typo3conf/ext/cookieconsent2/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xlf`
(and yes, mine is a German website!)

Emptying the cache at `Cache/Data/l10n/` as was suggested didn't work for me. Is there another solution?

Otherwise, I'll have to uninstall the extension, but it's hard to find something working for something as old as TYPO3 6.2 ...

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to go the Install Tool => Important Actions and hit the "Clear all Cache" button?

Another (untested) possibility:
Copy the template file `Resources/Private/Templates/Configuration.html` to your theme extension / sitepackage or even fileadmin and change the template path in TypoScript.

Then either hardcode the german text to the template or use your own translation labels which you can define in your TypoScript, e.g.

```
plugin.tx_cookieconsent2 {
  _LOCAL_LANG.de {
    myLabel = foo bar text
  }
}
```